# Use last part of URL as a query string in PHP rather than a directory path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I'm using a URL parameter in PHP to query my database and return certain client logos and data however I want to tidy up the links that I send out.

At the moment I use:

http://www.example.com/portal/index.php?id=client1

http://www.example.com/portal/index.php?id=client2

Which works fine but looks a bit untidy. Is there a way to use the following URL and use the last fragment as the parameter without creating directories for each?

http://www.example.com/portal/client1

http://www.example.com/portal/client2

I know how to extract the last part of the URL in php and use for the query but obviously as it stands this takes me to a "Not Found" directory.

Is there a way to tell my server not to treat this as a directory but load the index.php and I can extract the last URL fragment instead of a $_GET["id"];. Maybe changing the htaccess or another solution?

I'm running Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server

Thanks

Comment: Depends, what webserver are you using? (apache, nginx, ...)

Comment: Sorry Apache, Ubuntu

Comment: Can done with `.htaccess` like redirect `portal/(*)` to `portal/index.php?id=*`

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this in root,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ $1/index.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Put following in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirect /index.php?id=client1 to /index.php/client1 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php/%1? [L,R]
#internally forward /index.php/client1 to /index.php?id=client1 
RewriteRule ^index\.php/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This redirects to a 404 http://www.example.com/index.php/ABC - I was hoping to take me to http://www.example.com/portal/ABC (without the index.php in the URL but including "/portal/") but loads the page successfully.